# Removing auth_groups and auth_permission table from DB.(Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I don't want ***auth_group*** and ***auth_permission*** table in my DB as I'm not using groups and permission but I can't remove **django.contrib.auth** from the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py as I'm using ***login, authenticate*** modules of **contrib.auth**. I've unregistered Groups in admin.py so it doesn't appear in the admin panel.

Is there a way to avoid only these two (auth_groups, auth_permission) tables from my DB.

Also if I drop these two tables manually from DB will there be any effect on my project?

I have already talked to some folks they are suggesting not to drop these tables.

Comment: Any particular reason for wanting to remove them? I understand that you dont use them, but I myself have many projects where I dont use them, but those tables are still there and empty.
You could fork the official django repo and then remove it from the code there.

Comment: I honestly don't see why you should drop these. If you don't use these it will not have much impact on the rest. If you drop these it is possible that eventually if some permission check is done, you will get database errors. Django admin for example uses these groups and permissions to check if you can edit objects.

Comment: If you only use `login` and `authenticate` however with a custom user model, you don't need to add `auth` to the installed apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't see why you should drop these. If you don't use these it will not have much impact on the rest. The amount of disk used for an empty table is extremely small, and if you don't insert or update any records, there is also no performance bottleneck.

But even if you don't use these models, Django does. Indeed, staff members (users with `is_staff`) can log in to the `ModelAdmin` if these are not admin, Django checks if they have the permission to see, edit and remove model objects.

If you drop these it is possible that eventually if some permission check is done, you will get database errors. Django admin for example uses these groups and permissions to check if you can edit objects.

> but I can't remove `django.contrib.auth` from the `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py as I'm using `login`, `authenticate` modules of `contrib.auth`.

If you use these for a custom model, there is no need to add `django.contrib.auth` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. These functions work then with the custom user model, but since you seem to have "hidden" the `Group` model, I suspect that you use the builtin. Well if you use Django's builtin user model, then of course that ships with groups and permissions. If you use a custom user model, you can (to some extent) set the terms.

> Also if I drop these two tables manually from DB will there be any effect on my project?

Yes, Django has some views that perform permission checks, not at least on the `ModelAdmin`, so then for non-admin users, this will raise database errors.

> I have already talked to some folks they are suggesting not to drop these tables.

Manually changing the database is the worst one can do if the database is managed by another application, so that would indeed be a *very* bad idea.